# How FFmpeg multi-threaded download ts segment in m3u8 file?

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am using ffmpeg to download the ts in the m3u8 file and merge them into an mp4 file，Use the following command line：

```
ffmpeg -i <source m3u8 file> -c copy target.mp4
```

Although it can work, but I found the download speed is very slow, bandwidth utilization is very low, so I would like to know if ffmpeg can be set to multi-threaded download to speed up the download speed?

Comment: Not implemented.

Comment: @Gyan Now in 2022, does the newest ffmpeg support multi-thread? I found m3u8 downloading is about 22 times fast. But I want to playback 32 times fast. Does the official version support this now? thx!

Comment: @Gyan is your response from 2018 still applicable about this not being implemented (now that we're on version 5.1.x of FFMPEG)? Thanks